# Limiting the amount of divs returned from .find()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently gathering divs from every article on a single page then iterating through them to find all divs containing the class `.so-widget-hello-world-widget`. This is working fine however I am having trouble limiting it to only `5` per article.

I've tried using `slice`, `limit` and adding a counter but nothing seem to work.

Is there something obvious I am missing here?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('article').each(function(index, obj){
        var product = $(this).find('.so-widget-hello-world-widget')
        $(this).append(product)
    });
});
```

Comment: Worse case if Just code's solution doesn't work you could push everything into an array or object and get portions of them from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use lt selector [documetation](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/)

```
$(this).find('.so-widget-hello-world-widget:lt(5)')
```

```js
$('article').each(function(index, obj) {
  var products = $(this).find('.so-widget-hello-world-widget:lt(5)');
  products.each(function(index, el) {
    $(el).css({
      background: 'red'
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div1</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div2</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div3</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div4</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div5</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div6</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div7</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div8</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div9</div>
  <div class='so-widget-hello-world-widget'>div10</div>
</article>
```

Comment: uhgg:( added `var product = $(this).find('.so-widget-hello-world-widget:lt(5)')` to the loop but still returning all of the data for some reason. I'll keep looking into it. I dont get it because I feel like this is essentially just slice and that doesnt work either

Comment: It should work try debugging it or add jsfiddle let me take a look

Comment: ah ha! I was putting my script inside a php loop so it was just stacking on itself. got it working now though thanks for the help. Never heard about lt super usefull

Comment: @NooBskie glat it helps.